# passing function into another function in jquery?

Tags: html, jquery

I am passing json obj in the function parameter. Json contains User id, password, success call and error call.

I want to authentic the user via ajax service. if the service returns success the access the successcallback function or returns error then access the errorcallback function.

```
 JSON Obj : Json_Obj =  { "UserId" : "uid", 
                           "Password" : "pwd", 
                           "Success_CB" : "successcallback()",
                           "Failure_CB" : "errorcallback()",
                          };
```

I am able to parse the Json_Obj

```
  Authentication = function(data) {
    var json_data = $.parseJSON(data);
    $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
            .
            .
           success:function(data){
             json_data.Success_CB;   // Unable to Execute the success call back function.
            },
             error:function(xhr,err){
                    json_data.Failure_CB
             }
   });
 }          

   // Call Back Functions 

      successcallback(){
           alert("Success");
      }
      errorcallback(){
           alert("Error");
      }
```

I am unable to access/execute the callback functions.

Please help me out on this..

Comment: It's really a bad idea to pass function name, cannot you just pass the status back? Like "success" or "fail"

Comment: i think your json_data is out of scope for your success handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json_data.Success_CB` is a string, not a function.

You may do this :

```
success:function(data){
    eval(json_data.Success_CB+'();');
}
```

But instead of evaluating any received code, you might prefer to use a switch.

Of course if the function to call isn't related to the precise data, you may simply do

```
success: successcallback
```

Comment: why use eval? i think there is much better solution

Comment: @Mahan: you think or you know?

Comment: @Mahan It depends on the real goal, which is not described. That's why I proposed other solutions after having explained and solved the bug.

Answer (score 0):

You mean just like this?

```
  Authentication = function(data) {
    var json_data = $.parseJSON(data);
    $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           success:function(data){
                successcallback();
           },
           error:function(xhr,err){
                errorcallback();
           }
   });
 }          

   // Call Back Functions 

      successcallback(){
           alert("Success");
      }
      errorcallback(){
           alert("Error");
      }
```